# Spring Elasticsearch How to Apply the Following Mapping Parameters?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We need to incorporate the following mapping parameters in our java class fields:

'doc_values'
'norms'
'index'
'dynamic'

can somebody know what annotation/how to incorporate it on our field class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/Field.html) documentation where they have gievn all the param details which is supported for `@field` annotation.

```java
@Field(type = FieldType.Text, docValues = true)
private String authors;
```